# Why does the image within the box shrink upwards when the window shrinks?

Tags: html, css

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong here. I want the image inside the box to stay centered when the window shrinks. Furthermore, I would have thought that `align-items: center;` would work, but apparently not. The colors are only relevant for me, so I understand what's going on. I don't know if there is a solution for this either, but I hope so. And please ignore the naming and order of the individual classes, I couldn't do better ...:)

```css
.megadiv {
  max-width: 1600px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.centerbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left {
  width: 64%;
  background-color: red;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  display: flex;
}

.insideleft {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: yellow;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.insideright {
  width: 78%;
  background-color: purple;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 2%;
  text-align: left;
  border-left: 2px ridge #ffa54f;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
}

.picture {
  width: 80%;
  border-radius: 1%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 8%;
}

.right {
  width: 34%;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  height: 20px;
}

h7 {
  color: rgb(0, 153, 158);
  font-size: large;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.textpart {
  margin-bottom: 0.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="megadiv">
  <div class="centerbox">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="insideleft">
        <h20>
          <a href="">
            <img class="picture" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71hi8fWdX2L.jpg"> </a>
        </h20>
      </div>
      <div class="insideright">
        <h7><a href="">Headline</a></h7><br>
        <h4>
          <div class="textpart">Authors</div>
          <div class="textpart">Views <a class="" href="">Chapter 2</a></div>
          <div class="textpart">Genres: Action - Adventure - Comedy</div>
          <div class="textpart">Rating: ⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐</div>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        wawaeaweew
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

h4 and h20 are empty

Comment: "I want the image inside the box to stay centered" please clarify: centered vertically, horizontally?  Can we assume you mean the image in the left (yellow) pane?

Comment: yes and i want it vertically

Comment: Sorry thought it was obvious

Comment: FWIW note your `<div class="megadiv">` does not have a closing tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close to getting the image vertically aligned as you wanted. Try this out, and see if this works the way you would like:

```css
.megadiv {
  max-width: 1600px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.centerbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left {
  width: 64%;
  background-color: red;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  display: flex;
}

.insideleft {
  display: flex;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: yellow;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.insideright {
  width: 78%;
  background-color: purple;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 2%;
  text-align: left;
  border-left: 2px ridge #ffa54f;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
}

.picture {
  width: 80%;
  border-radius: 1%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 8%;
}

.right {
  width: 34%;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  height: 20px;
}

h7 {
  color: rgb(0, 153, 158);
  font-size: large;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.textpart {
  margin-bottom: 0.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="megadiv">
  <div class="centerbox">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="insideleft">
          <a href="">
            <img class="picture" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71hi8fWdX2L.jpg"> </a>
      </div>
      <div class="insideright">
        <h7><a href="">Headline</a></h7><br>
        <h4>
          <div class="textpart">Authors</div>
          <div class="textpart">Views <a class="" href="">Chapter 2</a></div>
          <div class="textpart">Genres: Action - Adventure - Comedy</div>
          <div class="textpart">Rating: ⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐</div>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        wawaeaweew
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I saw you used `align-items: center;` in the `.insideleft` CSS selector which is for aligning a container's children to the center like you want, you'll just want to make this a flexbox to make this work. To do this, simply add `display: flex;` to the `.insideleft` selector like in the example. I also removed the `<h20>` tag from the HTML as this is not valid or necessary.

As for the image shrinking down when the screen width is shrinked - this is because you're using percentages for the widths for all the containers and the image. If you want the image to stop shrinking after a certain point, you can add `min-width: 80px; /* (this can be any number of pixels) */` to your `.picture` selector to make the image stop shrinking once it gets to a certain width of pixels.

Flexbox is super useful for position elements in CSS and I'd recommend looking into this more to have a better understanding. Check out this link [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) if you'd like an overview of the different flexbox CSS properties.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure on your intent - Here I changed the class names a bit for clarity and adjusted the markup for a left-middle-right

Not a huge fan of % for padding and margin sizing myself (`em` feels more clear since it is based on the current font size)

Not strictly needed but I added the containing element class in a few places in CSS for clarity example: `.left-pane .picture-container`

```css
.page-container {
  max-width: 1600px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container-box {
  display: flex;
  align-content: space-between;
}

.container-box .left-pane {
  width: 20em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  border: 2px solid gray;
}

.left-pane .picture-container {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: yellow;
  align-items: center; /* vertical */
  align-content: center; /* horizontal */
}

.left-pane  .picture-container .picture {
  width: 80%;
  border-radius: 1%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 8%;
}

.container-box  .middle-pane {
  width: 70em;
  background-color: #FFDDDD;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  border-left: 2px ridge #ffa54f;
}

.middle-pane .headline {
  color: rgb(0, 153, 158);
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.middle-pane .textpart {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.container-box .right-pane {
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-container">
  <div class="container-box">
    <div class="left-pane">
      <div class="picture-container">
        <div>
          <a href="">
            <img class="picture" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71hi8fWdX2L.jpg"> </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="middle-pane">
      <div class="headline"><a href="">Headline</a></div>
      <h4>
        <div class="textpart">Authors</div>
        <div class="textpart">Views <a class="" href="">Chapter 2</a></div>
        <div class="textpart">Genres: Action - Adventure - Comedy</div>
        <div class="textpart">Rating: ⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐</div>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="right-pane">
      wawaeaweew
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```